# Adding th:each items to the Bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, thymeleaf, carousel, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to display 3 cards at the time inside the carousel using the th:each loop, but trying different things did not lead me to anything.

It would be great if 2 cards kept being shown for smaller screens, but the most important thing atm is to just make it work.

How would you do it?

```
<div th:if="${popularProducts != null}" class="row">
    <div th:each="product : ${popularProducts}" class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-6 mb-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title" th:text="${product.name}"></h5>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" style="font-size:14px" th:text="${product.published ? 'public' : 'private'}"></h6>
                <form th:action="@{/products/delete}" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>
                    <input type="hidden" th:name="productId" th:value="${product.id}"/>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn-close position-absolute top-0 end-0 me-2 mt-2" style="--bs-btn-padding-y: .4rem; --bs-btn-padding-x: 0.8rem; --bs-btn-font-size: 0.8rem;"></button>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="card-footer bg-transparent border-0">                  
                <div class="btn-group align-items-end" role="group" aria-label="Product Actions">
                    <form th:action="@{/p/{productId}(productId=${product.id})}" method="get">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info me-2 d-none d-sm-block" style="--bs-btn-padding-y: .4rem; --bs-btn-padding-x: 0.8rem; --bs-btn-font-size: 0.8rem;" th:text="'show requests'"></button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info me-2 d-sm-none" style="--bs-btn-padding-y: .4rem; --bs-btn-padding-x: 0.8rem; --bs-btn-font-size: 0.8rem;" th:text="'requests'"></button>
                    </form>
                    <form th:action="@{/products/{productId}(productId=${product.id})}" method="get">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info me-2" style="--bs-btn-padding-y: .4rem; --bs-btn-padding-x: 0.8rem; --bs-btn-font-size: 0.8rem;" th:text="edit"></button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```